# How can I use a value in a function item?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have an ionic 4 angular app

i have this in my component

```
export class TestPage implements OnInit {
a1 =false;
a2 =false;
...
```

i have this in my html

```
    <ion-item  (click)="action('a1')">
    <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Sample 1</ion-label>      
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item  (click)="action('a2')">
    <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Sample 1</ion-label>      
    </ion-item>
```

i need to get something like this

```
action(value){
 this.value= true;
 // i would like to get this.a2 cahnged to true
}
```

i need to change a1 (or a2) to true, i dont know how to use valueto change 'this.item'

i need to use the 'value' because there are several items and i dont want to make 1 function for every item.

somebody can guide me in the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do change in your html like below

```
<ion-item  (click)="action(true)">
    <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Sample 1</ion-label>      
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item  (click)="action(true)">
    <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Sample 2</ion-label>      
    </ion-item>
```

and in your ts file

```
action(value){
 this.a2= value;
 //or this.a1 = value
}
```

**Updated**

and you wanna to use one function for every field than you have to do somthing like below

In your html file

```
<ion-item  (click)="action(true,'a1')">
        <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Sample 1</ion-label>      
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item  (click)="action(true,'a2')">
        <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">Sample 2</ion-label>      
        </ion-item>
```

and in your ts file

```
action(value:boolean,fieldName:string){
    switch (fieldName) {
          case "a1":
            this.a1 =value; 
            break;
          case "a2":
            this.a2 = value
            break;
          default:
            console.log("No such day exists!");
            break;
        }
       }
```

Hope this will help you

thanks

Comment: @diegojimenez let me know what you want exactly

Comment: I can not use 'this.a2' inside function because these are several similar items and i would have to create one function for every item. I would like 'this.(variable)' or something similar

Comment: look at the answer once again, it will not full fill your exact requirement what you want, but possible thing that I have updated. thanks